# Proof verification: finite/non-finite subset X of an ordered field contains/doesn't contain a smallest element and a largest element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, field-theory, solution-verification

I have the following assignment and am wondering if my approach towards the proof is correct.

> Prove that every non-empty finite subset X of an ordered field contains
> a smallest element and a largest element. (A smallest element is
> an element x ∈ X such that x ≤ y for all y ∈ X; a largest element is
> defined similarly.) Is the same true if we drop the condition that X be
> finite?

Finite subset:

Let's suppose $X \subseteq O$, where $X \neq \emptyset $, $O$ is any ordered field and $X$ is finite. We pick whichever element of $X$ and then select the next larger one. We continue repeating the previous step, however since $X$ is finite we eventually run out of elements to select from and the last selected element is thus the largest one. A similar, albeit slightly modified procedure applies for the smallest element. As such any finite non-empty subset of an ordered field contains the biggest and the smallest element.

Non-finite subset (proof by counter-example):

Let $X = (0, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ (assuming the non-finiteness of $X$ and $\mathbb{R}$ being an ordered field). Suppose (for contradiction) that $\lambda$ is the largest element of $X$. But $\frac{\lambda+1}{2}$ $\in X$ and $\lambda \lt \frac{\lambda+1}{2}$. Thus there is no largest element. Similarly, assume that $\mu$ is the smallest element of $X$. But $\frac {\mu}{2}\in X$ and $\mu \gt \frac{\mu}{2}$. Hence there is no smallest element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform induction on the number of the members of the finite set. For the maximum ( identical to greatest element in an ordered field) statement.

If $X$ is a singleton, the statement trivially holds. Assume it holds for all finite sets with  $n$ members. Let’s see if the statement holds if $X$ has $n+1$ distinct members. Form the sets $X_k$ which contain all members of $X$ except the $k$th one. Calculate $\max X_k$ using the hypothesis. In $n+1$ steps, you can check whether $ \max X_k < x_k$ holds or not. There is at most one index $k$ where the statement: if not and it holds for $k=l$and $k=j$, then $x_l\leq \max X_j < x_j$ and similarly, $x_j<x_l$. This is impossible by trichotomy. There is at least one value of $k$ where the statement holds: if not, for all $k$, there exists $l$ such that $x_k< \max X_k = x_l$. Then, $x_l < \max X_l < x_k$ by $X_l = X_k\setminus \{x_l\}\cup \{x_k\}$ and the definition of maximum in an ordered field. Again, this is a contradiction.